# are there any CSS properties that have both 'auto' and 'none' values?

Tags: css, default

Or I can safely assume if a property has `auto` then it can't have `none` value and vice versa if a property has `none` than it can't have `auto`.

I know that meaning of these is distinctive, but I wonder if it has been used in CSS yet.

I wonder if a property have auto or none it is safe to assume that this is the default value.

Comment: Depends on what you define as none, i guess. `margin:0;` can be considered as none. And then you have its counter part, `margin:auto`.

Comment: Why do you think `auto` and `none` are necessarily mutually exclusive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, the [hyphens property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#hyphens) in the *CSS Text Level 3* draft has the values none | manual | auto (and the property [is being implemented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/hyphens#AutoCompatibilityTable) though for the time being browsers probably recognize it only when a vendor prefix is used in the name).